# JITSU FAILED TO INSTALL OSX [node 0.8.17 and NPM 1.2.0] WTF

Tags: node.js, npm, nodejitsu

im having problems installing jitsu through NPM
i have node 0.8.17 and NPM 1.2.0 installed on my mac osx 10.6.8

when i run

$ sudo npm install jitsu -g
First it warns about no readme file found

```
npm WARN package.json ladder@0.0.0 No README.md file found!
```

then the errors appear:

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/request/tests/test-toJSON.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR! http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR! npm-@googlegroups.com

npm ERR! System Darwin 10.8.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "jitsu" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local/share
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/request/tests/test-toJSON.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/request/tests/test-toJSON.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/npm/doc'
npm ERR! error rolling back jitsu@0.11.4 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/npm/doc']
npm ERR! error rolling back errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/npm/doc' }
npm ERR! Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/flatiron'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR! http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR! npm-@googlegroups.com

npm ERR! System Darwin 10.8.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "jitsu" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local/share
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/flatiron
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! errno 53
npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/wizard/node_modules/prompt/docs'
File exists: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/wizard/node_modules/prompt/docs
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Darwin 10.8.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "jitsu" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local/share
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/wizard/node_modules/prompt/docs
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/wizard/node_modules/prompt/docs/docco.css
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/fstream-npm/node_modules/fstream-ignore/test/.npmignore'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR! http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR! npm-@googlegroups.com

npm ERR! System Darwin 10.8.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "jitsu" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local/share
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/fstream-npm/node_modules/fstream-ignore/test/.npmignore
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu/node_modules/fstream-npm/node_modules/fstream-ignore/test/.npmignore
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all remove that old jitsu directory: `[sudo] rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu`. Then clear your npm cache: `npm cache clear` and try again: `[sudo] npm install jitsu -g`

Comment: `npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jitsu'`

Comment: Are you running that as root? You probably should be.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else having this issue you need 2 commands:

```
npm cache clear
sudo npm install jitsu -g
```

At Nodejitsu"s github they recommend to install it without [sudo] on OSX but seems to fail on 10.6.8

Happy coding!

Comment: I had this issue, and these commands didn't fix it, until I also ran "sudo npm update npm -g" to update npm itself.